# Upper bound on the spectral radius of summation of two matrices one symmetric one diagonal

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, upper-lower-bounds, spectral-radius

I am looking for an upper bound for the largest absolute value of eigenvalues of the summation of two matrices $\underset{i}\max\{|\lambda_i(A+K)|\}$ where $A$ is symmetric with real nonnegative eigenvalues and $K$ is a diagonal matrix.

Any idea is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Is $A$ a real matrix, or just a symmetric (maybe non-hermitian) complex matrix with real eigenvalues?

Comment: $A$ is a real matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDITED]
If $M$ and $m$ are the greatest and least diagonal elements of $K$ respectively, $$\lambda_{min}(A)+m = \lambda_{min}(A+mI) \le \lambda_{min}(A+K) \le \lambda_{max}(A+K) \le \lambda_{max}(A+MI) = \lambda_{max}(A)+M$$
Thus $|\lambda_i(A+K)| \le \max(|\lambda_{min}(A)+m|, |\lambda_{max}(A)+M|)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
May I ask how you prove,
$\lambda_{\max}(A+K) \leq \lambda_{\max}(A+MI)$ ?
And also aren't $M$ and $m$ the "absolute value" of greatest and least diagonal elements of $K$ respectively?

Comment: No, $M$ and $m$ are the greatest and least as I said.  The proof uses the [min-max theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem).

Comment: **Thanks a lot**                                         !

Comment: May I also ask if this upper bound is a convex function? 
There is also another property that we know about $A+K$ which is all its eigenvalues are negative.

Comment: A convex function of what?